# The links from my pagination script disappear after page 1

Tags: php

Me back again whit a PHP mySQLi pagination problem...
When I rune the script it works fine for first page, but when y click on the link to the second pages te links works but the pagination disappears. so if I have 3 links now I see none.
Here's my code.

```
<?php

    include_once ('myConnection.php');

    if ( isset( $_GET["get_name"] ) ) { 
        $las_escuelas = $_GET["get_name"];
    } else { 
        $las_escuelas = 1; 
    };

    $start_from = ( $las_escuelas - 1 ) * 10;

    $escuelas = "SELECT * 
                   FROM escuelas 
                   WHERE delegacion = '$delegacion' 
                     AND nivel = '$nivel' 
                   ORDER BY nombre ASC 
                   LIMIT $start_from, 10";

    $consulta = mysqli_query( $miguia, $escuelas ) or die ( mysqli_error() );

    while ( $fila = mysqli_fetch_array( $consulta ) ) {
        echo $fila['name'] . '<br>' . $fila['street'] . ' ' . $fila['numero'] . ' ' . $fila['place'] . ' ' . $fila['phone'] . '<br>';
    };

    $escuelas = "SELECT COUNT(delegacion) 
                   FROM escuelas 
                   WHERE delegacion = '$delegacion' 
                     AND nivel = '$nivel'";

    $consulta = mysqli_query( $miguia, $escuelas );
    $fila = mysqli_fetch_row( $consulta );
    $registros_total = $fila[0];
    $paginas_total = ceil( $registros_total / 10 );

    for ( $i = 1; $i <= $paginas_total; $i++ ) {
        echo "<a href='resultados1.php?las_escuelas=".$i."'>".$i."</a> ";
    };

?>
```

Thank's :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think (it's pretty hard to "reverse engineer Spanish code :) that you should start your for cycle from $i = 0 instead of 1.

Comment: OK I found the problem... the code is fine Thanks to jonathan-sampson for pointing out my space errors, and as I was translating to English I found that the problem was in the link at the bottom, it was sending the URL  to another results page. Sorry for that.